# Determine default colour of background of Android buttons

Tags: android, button

How can I find the colour used for a default button's background, both when it is clicked and not. I've tried to use `android.R.drawable.btn_default` for not clicked, but this color is lighter then default on my tablet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then use custom color using `selector` eg *customstyle.xml* under **drawable** and using this as background for your button. Sample code its working fine for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item  android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="#f8f9fa" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#d2d2d2" />
        <corners
            android:radius="1dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#f8f9fa"
            android:endColor="#d2d2d2"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#d2d2d2" />
        <corners
            android:radius="1dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```